# Why/how does Gupta have Buck's knife?

Tags: ice-age-4, ice-age-5

In ice age 3, we are introduced to the crazy weasel Buck. One of the most defining things about him (other than his eyepatch) is his knife (he got both at the same time). Here is a still of him with it:

[image]

Later, in Ice age 4, we see Gupta, one of Gutt's crew give Weiner his knife:

[image: is this the same knife??]

Later on we see buck still having his knife in ice age 5.

[image]

To me, these seem to be the same knife, and I'm not alone: [someone has already asked this question](http://www.answers.com/Q/Is_buck's_knife_in_ice_age_4). However, the answer they got was not very helpful.

Is there a better explanation as to how a seafaring pirate got a dino-tooth (and not just any Dino! This is the tooth of Rudy himself!) knife, or is it just animator laziness?

Comment: No one knows. My guess would be that Buck used to be a member of that pirate crew, that Gutt saved his life from Rudy and THAT’S how Gutt got the tooth, he saved Buck from Rudy.

Comment: I know it's not official but the ice age wiki classifies the dagger Gupta had as another knife. https://iceage.fandom.com/wiki/Rudy%27s_Tooth

Answer (score 1):

I think the resemblance is just that. They probably just couldn't be bothered to make another original "rugged knife" model for the movie, so they just used Buck's Knife model instead. Maybe it was a placeholder for until they made another knife, but they accidentally left it in.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but I noticed in the ice age: adventures of buck wild.. momma Rex was missing one of her lower moalers.. even though it's a spin off maby they tried to fit in an explanation for there being another very similar knife. And buck talks about how he had an old team with Z who all died. Perhaps gutt was part of that team and turned on them by fighting with momma Rex.. taking one of her teeth.. and if he was part of that team it would explain why the knife was crafted just like bucks? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

It can not be the theory about the adventures of buck wild because it's not made by the original creators of ice age, but that is a whole new story. But my guess is that the pirates heard buck's story and wanted to look cool by making a similar looking knife. If not then I would think that the editors wanted to make people curious and watch every movie to find out why (even though they won't get their answer.) It would just give them money.

Answer (score -1):

I think they didn't intend on making the 5th movie so in the 4th they were trying to imply that the crew had captured (and most likely killed) Buck and that's why Gupta had his knife.

Comment: Welcome to Movies&TV, can you maybe source your statement by adding some links or quote ?